# How to place two forms together inline

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for layout of my project and basically I have two a `div` like this:

```
<div>
    <form action="{{ route('destroy.question', $post->id) }}" method="POST">
        @csrf
        @method('DELETE')
        <button class="btn">
        Delete
        </button>
    </form>
    <form action="{{ route('edit.question', $post->id) }}">
        <button class="btn">
        Edit 
        </button>
    </form>
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary">
    Discussion
    </a>
</div>
```

And here is the picture of this:

[image]

So I need to make this `div` inline, therefore the two forms and the link, are all placed in just on row.

I tried adding `class="row"` and `class="form-inline"` but didn't fix!

So if you know how to do that, just let me know, I would really appreciate that,

Thanks.

Comment: add `d-inline-block` class for each `form` and `a`, **or** `d-flex` class for `div`.

Comment: For future reference, only add tags that are relevant to the issue at hand. I removed the PHP tag for you since this is a pure html/css question.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov Bootstrap 3 doesnt have flexbox support so it depends on what version the OP is using. If 4+ then your suggestion works but below that, it won’t.

Comment: @Ajay, Yes, but the OP did not specify version bootstrap, so I gave a universal answer. `d-inline-block` work on version 3.

Comment: @s.kuznetsov that’s interesting. I am pretty sure that the d- properties dont exist in v3.x. These were introduced in v4

Comment: @Ajay, May be. I don’t know bootstrap very well. Since I don’t see the point in css frameworks. But the classes defining inline block bootstrap 3 are exactly supported. It is enough for the author to simply indicate the version and the guesses become obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add

```css
.inline { display: inline }
```

and replace your `<form` with `<form class=“inline”` and do the same for the anchor tag

———————

Also, a better approach using flexbox would be

```css
.inline { display: flex }
```

and replace your `<div` with `<div class=“inline”`